# Complex ViewModel into razor forms in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a complex viewmodel. How can I make a form for it?

```
public class ProductViewModel{
  public string ProductName {get;set;}
  public double Price {get;set;}
  public BrandViewModel brand {get;set;}
  public CategoryViewModel category {get;set;}
}

public class BrandViewModel{
  public string BrandName {get;set;}
  public string BrandRegYear {get;set;}
}

public class CategoryViewModel{
  public string CategoryName {get;set;}
  public bool IsISOStandard {get;set;}
}
```

How can I create razor form for ProductViewModel?

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.brand.BrandName) @Html.EditorFor(model => model.category.CategoryName)` among your other composite view model properties like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)` ,if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume brand and categories are prefilled tables/models?
First, maybe add an Id column on those two tables (if you haven't already).

Then in the view model, only add the Id column (i.e. Remove `public BrandViewModel brand {get;set;}` and add `public int BrandId {get;set;}`.

Perhaps use a dropdown (or list or ) for UI. If the list is small, add it to a view bag (if the list is large, call it with client / JS / ajax).

Something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrandId)
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BrandId, ViewBag.Brands as SelectList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandId, "Blah blah blah bad input blah blah", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```